# Log Unique IP Addresses using PHP

Tags: php

I want to have a script that only logs an IP address that has not before been logged to a text file. I hope to be able to accomplish this without having to use MySQL or any other database.

IP’s are stored like this:

```
IP: 127.0.0.1 15 May, 2015, 12:01 pm
```

Basically, I don’t want the log to look like this:

```
IP: 127.0.0.1 15 May, 2015, 12:01 pm
IP: 127.0.0.1 15 May, 2015, 12:08 pm
IP: 127.0.0.1 15 May, 2015, 12:17 pm
```

Right now, here is my PHP code:

```
$check = fopen("ip.txt", "r");
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$exists = FALSE;

while ($ln = fgetcsv($check, 200, "\n") !== FALSE) {
       if ($ln[1] == $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) {
           $exists = TRUE;
       }
}
fclose($check);

if ($exists == TRUE) {
    // do nothing
}
else if ($exists == FALSE) {
    $file = fopen("ip.txt", "a");
    $date = date("j F, Y, g:i a");
    $string = "IP: " . $ip . " " . $date . "\n";
    fwrite($file, $string);
    fclose($file);
}
```

The above is currently not working, and I have many duplicate IP addresses in my `ip.txt` file. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How many unique IPs do you expect to capture?

Comment: You would be opening a text file and parse it ever time someone hits your site. Another approach may be to append to the file and take care of duplication when you want to read the data.

Comment: Why oh why not use a database for this?   For the above reason, easy searching, separation, queries, the list could go on.

Comment: @Lance, probably 4.3 billion. (</sarcasm>)

Comment: I think using a text file will get real bulky real fast even if you only get 2.1 billion hits. :D

Comment: @Devon, I just want to see if it's possible. I'm only doing this for an internal network for curiosities sake. If I were doing this for real world application, I would obviously use a database :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ln = fgetcsv($check, 200, "\n") !== FALSE
```

As comparison (!==) have higher precedence then assignment, the line above is equivalent to the following:

```
$ln = (fgetcsv($check, 200, "\n") !== FALSE)
```

while you probably wanted it to read something like that:

```
($ln = fgetcsv($check, 200, "\n")) !== FALSE
```

Note: I didnt check the rest of the code.